# How can I animate a moving circle to a bigger circle using Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael

I have a circle with `x=50`, `y=30` and `radius = 20`. 
This circle should move in 1000 ms to a new position `x=150`, `y=170` and `radius = 30`.

These are my objects:

```
paper.circle(50, 30, 20);
paper.newCircle(150, 170, 30);
```

Now I want to animate a movement, so it looks like the first circle moves to the second one but with a bigger radius.

Much like the first example [here](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/animation.html) (click on the arrow) but it should have a bigger radius after the animation.

This should be pretty simple but I can not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in an object to the animate method, and pass it a duration, like follows.

```
var c = paper.circle(50, 30, 20);
c.animate({ r: 30, cx: 150, cy: 170 }, 1000);
```